# What's the best way to draw, review react components tree

Tags: reactjs, react-native

My team is starting with new react project, I’m trying to draw components tree and get it reviewed before starting coding

```
Parent-1
   Child-1
      Child-1-1
      Child-1-2
   Child-2
      Child-2-1
        Child-2-2-1
```

I’m looking for better way to draw react components tree and share with team.

I tried JIRA but it’s spoiling format of tree structure, also team members not able to comment on particular child component or give suggestion properly.

Can you please suggest better way ?

Comment: take a photo of react-devtools?

Comment: App development has not yet started. As per https://reactjs.org/docs/thinking-in-react.html,  want to get components family tree reviewed and approved beforehand to avoid costly fixes later